# Questions about monotone sequences and subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following questions about sequence:

1. Does every monotone sequence have a bounded subsequence?
2. Does every bounded sequence have a monotone subsequence?
3. Does every sequence have a subsequence for which the limit makes sense?
4. If lim sup $a_n$ is finite, then the sequence $a_n$ is bounded above?

I think the answers should be False, True, True, and True, but I cannot come up with a valid reasoning or counter examples. Can anybody help?

Comment: What does it mean for the limits to "make sense" in question $3$?

Comment: I mean the limit exists either finite or infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. False.  Consider the sequence $1,2,3,\dots$
2. True.  In fact, every sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence.  This is the [monotone subsequence theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotone-subsequence-theorem).
3. True.  This follows from question $2$.
4. True.  If a sequence is not bounded above, then it has a subsequence that diverges to $\infty$, so the lim sup is infinite.